# How to deal with requirement changes in agile development model?

Tags: agile

I know that in agile requirement changes should not only be planned for but also embraced. But I still don't know agile how to handle these changes.

Comment: You shouldnt cross post but instead wait for you question to be migrated. Please go back and delete the original question if it is no longer required.

Comment: I think different development model has different way to deal with changing requirement? for example, Lean and prescriptive?

Comment: Agreed, as much as I think this is a basic question that could be answered with 30 seconds on google, it is distinct from the one it is marked as duplicate of.

Answer (score 3):

"Responding to change over following a plan", Is one of the four points of the [Agile Manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/).

In a typical methodology, such as Scrum, there are a number of tools that help do that.
You don't deliver everything in one hit, instead deliver incrementally, incorporating feedback into the product backlog.

The Product backlog is a prioritised wish list of features that the product owner wants. Unlike a specification, this isn't fully detailed and can be changed at the product owners discretion. The highest priority items are elaborated enough such that development can be executed and may be selected for the next Sprint.

During a Sprint developers commit to deliver a selection of the high priority items and it is at this point that changes are typically locked down. A Sprint typically lasts 1-4 weeks (I most frequently see 2 week sprints). At the end of a Sprint, there should be a potentially shippable product.